# Displaying Index column in mui-datatables

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement to display row index for every row in my table. I see two options:

- Server side data loading
- Using customRowRender

Both options have some downsides. And I am surprised this feature doesn't come out-of-the box.

Are there some other options? I would prefer to be able to load all data into the browser, but with customRowRender I won't be able to keep original row styling...

Comment: Did you check this :- https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables Hope this will help in your case.

Comment: Yes, I checked. Even looked at source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add an extra column to a source dataset with undefined or empty string value and then to use a custom cell body render function:

```
export function customRowIndexColumn() {
    return ({
        name: '#',
        options: {
            filter: false,
            customBodyRender: (value: any, meta: MUIDataTableMeta) => {
                return (
                    meta.rowIndex + 1
                );
            }
        }
    })
}
....

    const columns: MUIDataTableColumnDef[] = [
        customRowIndexColumn(),
        {
            name: 'Plane ID',
            options: {
                filter: false
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Name',
            options: {
                filter: false
            }
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use customBodyRender pass rowIndex and dataIndex, then access dataIndex.rowIndex
it has worked for me

```
        name: "id",
        label: "#",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: true,
            customBodyRender: (rowIndex, dataIndex) => dataIndex.rowIndex + 1 
        }
    },
```

increment with 1 to start at position 1